# Read Richtextbox first line when true then next line when false in every tick

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaTlw.png)

This is what I am aiming to do. In everytime the clock ticks, and i get some errors
Well this is my codes so far.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get current time
        int hh = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        int mm = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        int ss = DateTime.Now.Second;
        int ms = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        //time
        string time = "";
        //padding leading zero
        if (hh < 10)
        { time += hh; }
        else
        {

            if (hh >= 12)
            {
                int h = hh - 12;
                if (h == 0)
                {

                    time += 12;
                }
                else
                {
                    time += h;
                }

            }
            else { time += hh; }


        }

        time += ":";
        if (mm < 10)
        { time += "0" + mm; }
        else
        { time += mm; }
        time += ":";
        if (ss < 10)
        { time += "0" + ss; }
        else
        { time += ss; }
        //update Ltime label
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        // SerialPort.GetPortNames() returns multiple strings in an array, not just one string.

        //You need to go through each item in the array, and run your Contains() and Add() for each item.
        foreach (var p in ports) // Go through each string in the array
        {
            if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(p))
                comboBox1.Items.Add(p);
        }


        if (hh < 12)
        { Ltime.Text = time + "am"; }
        else { Ltime.Text = time + "pm"; }

        int count = sched1.Lines.Count();//isulod sa var count kung pila ka line unod ni sched1.Text
        if (count == i)
        {
            display2.Text = "No Available Schedule";
        }
        else
        {
            /////reading the schedules
            for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sched1.Lines[x+1]))
                {
                    display2.Text = "Empty";
                }
                /////okay ni/
                else
                {

                    if (sched1.Lines[x+1] == (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString()))
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sched2.Text))
                        {
                            display2.Text = "Empty";
                        }
                        ///okay mn
                        else
                        {
                            int count2 = sched2.Lines.Count();
                            if (count2 == i)
                            {
                                display2.Text = "No Available Schedule";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                for (int y = 0; x < count2; y++)
                                    if (sched2.Lines[y+1].Equals(Ltime.Text))
                                    {


                                        serialPort1.Write("1");

                                        try
                                        {
                                            display2.Text = serialPort1.ReadExisting();


                                        }
                                        catch (TimeoutException)
                                        {
                                            display2.Text = "Timeout Exception";
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else { display2.Text = "Empty"; }
                    //ok mn
                }
            }
        }

        }
  But it display  "Index was outside the bounds of the array." in
```

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sched1.Lines[x+1])) I don't know what would be the problem.

Comment: Please see the Image first that is what I want to do

Comment: your variable x is counting from the first index (0) to the last index (count - 1) and then you want to get the line "x+1" which will be an OutOfRange Exception in the last loop, same with y. So Either if you don't want to get the first line, then you have to start x and y at one else you can leave it at 0 and you also have to change it to sched1.Lines[x] instead of sched1.Lines[x+1], same with y and sched2

Comment: I have tried this instead, If the DaysOfWeek is available inside the richboxtext. then go to the next richboxtext then check if the given time is available insidde the second richboxtext. If it is available display switching on. I don't know if it will work